# Using Class Template in Visual C++

Tags: c++

I wrote template which return matrix in Window Form Application .My template is below:

```
   template<class T>
    class matrix1 {
    protected:  

    public:
          T *data;

            const unsigned rows, cols, size;
            matrix1(unsigned r, unsigned c) : rows(r), cols(c), size(r*c) {

          data = new T[size];
            }
            ~matrix1() { delete data; }
            void setValue(unsigned row, unsigned col, T value) { 
                    data[(row*cols)+col] = value;
            }
            T getValue(unsigned row, unsigned col) const {
                    return data[(row*cols)+col];
            }
```

I wrote this code in Main Project File in Windows Form Application.I defined 341*680 matrix with using this template :

```
matrix1<double>A(341,680);
```

I used function that do operation on this template and I defined it like this:

```
void function(matrix1<double> &b,array< double>^ data)
```

And call it:

```
function(A,data);
```

(data is one dimensinonal data array that I have to use for my programming algorithm)

For Example;When I want to print  data that is located in the first row and first column.

Visual C++ recognise **getvalue**  and `setvalue` function ,but couldn't print anything and gave a lot of error interested with **matrix1** template

I tried this template and function on **CLR Console Application** and it worked.How could I do this On Windows Form Application.And Where should I locate template class on Windows Form Application.

Best Regards...

Comment: What is the error? What do you mean by print in a WinForms application?

Comment: Also, what is the array1 template?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have a bug in the destructor, it should be

```
~matrix1() { delete []data; }
```